# Unexpected behaviour datetime.strptime parse when the format string lacks spaces

Tags: python, python-datetime

Trying to parse and validate a date and hour that has to have "yyyymmddhh" format. I want the function to raise an exception if the string does not conform the specified format, so I test two ill formed strings that hasn't the hour part:

Test 1. Results as expected

```
>>> datetime.strptime("20230609", "%Y%m%d%H")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '20230609' does not match format '%Y%m%d%H'
```

Test 2. Bug?

Only changing date from June 9th to June 10th:

```
>>> datetime.strptime("20230610", "%Y%m%d%H")
datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 1, 0, 0)
```

As I understand, %Y, %m, %d and %H expect zero padded fixed length numbers with a total of 10 chars, so the lack of spaces shoudn't fool the parser. Am i mistaken?

Tested on python 3.7 and 3.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note 9 in the documentation indicates the leading 0 is optional with `strptime`:

> When used with the `strptime()` method, the leading zero is optional for formats `%d`, `%m`, `%H`, `%I`, `%M`, `%S`, `%j`, `%U`, `%W`, and `%V`. Format `%y` does require a leading zero.

So `strptime` takes advantage of the fact that it can consume `2023` with `%Y`, `06` with `%m`, but only `1`, not `10`, with `%d`, leaving `0` to match `%H`.

With `20230609`, `0` is not a valid day or month, so there is no interpretation that allows `%Y%m%d` to consume fewer than 8 characters, leaving nothing for `%H`.

Comment: Understood. I only wonder if it is possible to validate the date-hour not needing to additionally test for length or regex outside of strptime, as I wish my format string could be changed without needing to review other validation code that depends on the exact format